# Windows 7 Redirected Folders Root

Tags: windows-7

I have setup redirected folders for Windows 7 (using a Server 2008 R2 domain controller set to 2008 R2 mode) but I am having a problem.

I have redirected all of the available folders (e.g. Documents, Photos, Music, Favourites) but there isn't a GPO setting to redirect the entire User folder. What if someone saves a file to their user folder root?

e.g \server\redirected_folders$\john\file_goes_here.doc

instead of \server\redirected_folders$\john\Documents\file.doc

Where would this file be stored? In the roaming profile? What if we use mandatory profiles?

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be called their profile location, it's configured in AD Users & Computers, under the user's account. It will create a roaming profile for the users in the network share you setup for it.